# Font Awesome icons not rendering in my top links

Tags: magento2, header

I have added the Font Awesome cdn link in my header.

```
(default_head_block.xml)

css rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" src_type="url"/>
```

Then added the link to facebook in the top links

```
(default.xml)
block 

class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="facebook" before="-"

arguments

 argument

 name="label" xsi:type="string" i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x" /i>

/argument

argument name="path" xsi:type="string">https://www.facebook.com/ 

/argument

/arguments

/block
```

I have cleared the cache and reindexed. But the  element doesnt seem to render.

I can see the FB link, but the icon wont show. 
Also, the Font Awesome CDN appears in the header so I know its loading.

What am I doing wrong? 
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix a HTML element in Magento's XML. The XML parser for the current link class takes a string.

If you look in the class `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current`

```
/**
 * Render block HTML
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (false != $this->getTemplate()) {
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    $highlight = '';

    if ($this->getIsHighlighted()) {
        $highlight = ' current';
    }

    if ($this->isCurrent()) {
        $html = '<li class="nav item current">';
        $html .= '<strong>'
            . $this->escapeHtml((string)new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($this->getLabel()))
            . '</strong>';
        $html .= '</li>';
    } else {
        $html = '<li class="nav item' . $highlight . '"><a href="' . $this->escapeHtml($this->getHref()) . '"';
        $html .= $this->getTitle()
            ? ' title="' . $this->escapeHtml((string)new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($this->getTitle())) . '"'
            : '';
        $html .= $this->getAttributesHtml() . '>';

        if ($this->getIsHighlighted()) {
            $html .= '<strong>';
        }

        $html .= $this->escapeHtml((string)new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($this->getLabel()));

        if ($this->getIsHighlighted()) {
            $html .= '</strong>';
        }

        $html .= '</a></li>';
    }

    return $html;
}
```

You will see `$this->escapeHtml((string)new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($this->getLabel()))` this call to escape the HTML. So your call to the font is stripped out before it's rendered.

The only way I have been able to get this to work is to place the call to the icon in a .phtml. So in your case, you might just call a template file from the default.xml you are using and call the icons in there. This would be how you would pull a template into the footer container:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
    <container name="social_footer" label="Social Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="social-footer" before="-">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="social.footer" template="Magento_Theme::html/custom-social.phtml"/>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

And then create a file at `app/design/frontend/{{Vendor}}/{{Theme}}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/custom-social.phtml`

Comment: So just add template="Magento_Theme::html/social.phtml " and then declare the font awesome i elements in there?

Comment: Yep, updated my answer with the code you need to do that.

Comment: I created the phtml templates and have added in the ul to match both the  Footer & Header links. I can inspect and see the elements (ul -> a) and if I put the text in it will appear. But the "i" class doesnt show. I have set it a height & width (background-color to check its there), but it wont render. I thought maybe the Font Awesome CDN might not be loading, but it appears in the network activity to be loading fine?

Comment: I ran a test using `<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> fa-camera-retro` in a phtml and it's showing up in my dev site. As long as the file is showing test in the right place, then i would assume you have everything set up in Magento correctly. Now it's just trouble shooting FA. Are you getting any of the elements showing up in the dom when you inspect it? Do you see the link to the CDN in the header when you view the source of the page?

Comment: Yes, the element appears and if I place text inside `<i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg">Facebook</i>` it will show (albeit in italics). I've checked the head and seen that Font Awesome is loading. Just tried changing the colour, incase it was something silly like that, but no luck. I can see the element in dev tools and it does add aria-hidden="true" so I guess its loading. But nothings showing. I'm starting to think its something really basic that I'm over looking?

Comment: When I apply simple style (width + height + background-color) to the "li.nav.links.social" it appears, but if I apply the same to "li.nav.links.social a" it doesn't? The href is 0px x 0px.

Comment: Found my mistake. I didn't add the correct file path. Problem solved.

Comment: SWEET! Good to hear.

Answer (score 1):

Did you inspect the network tab as well to check if the file you try to include via CDN really is loaded and not just listed as a link element?

Comment: Have just checked and it has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `css href="..."` into `css src="..."`

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried it, but it didn't fix it. I think (though I have no reason why) that it's the <i> element?

Comment: Hmm. Can you check if your element is correctly rendered?